# Cypress Timeout after even the page is present

Tags: cypress

To avoid adding `cy.wait`, am trying to user the explicit wait, but seems it is broken. What I missed here

```
const APIAccountPage= {
    APIAccount(name) {
        //cy.wait(14000);
        cy.server();
        cy.route('GET', '/api/accounts').as('Accounts');
        cy.wait('@Accounts', { timeout: 10000 })
            .its('status').should('eq', 200);
        cy.get('.vbutton__baseline___3XNit.fonts__letterSpacing___3l5GB.styles__searchIconWrapper___19oVL.styles__iconButton___LLzft')
            .should('be.visible')
            .should('not.be.disabled');
        cy.get('.vbutton__baseline___3XNit.fonts__letterSpacing___3l5GB.styles__searchIconWrapper___19oVL.styles__iconButton___LLzft').click();
        cy.wait(4000);
        cy.get('.styles__patientSearchClass___2iGOV').type(name);
        cy.wait(4000);
        cy.get('.styles__patientSearchClass___2iGOV').contains(name).click();
    }

}

module.exports = APIAccountPage;
```

**Error Details**

[image]

**Cypress Window**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following, if the `/api/account` is not working, there may be multiple reason, one of which I am thinking is a `backend api` (which happened in my case) for which you need to handle the authentication.

If it is same then try to provide the complete URL like,

```
cy.server()
        cy.route(
            'GET',
            'https://<URL>/api/accounts',
            '{"errors":[]}',
        ).as('account');
```

and call  `cy.wait('@account')` whichever place is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Just a sidenote `cy.server()` and `cy.route` has been deprecated since 6.0.0, you can read about it from [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server). Instead, a new method has been introduced called `cy.intercept()`.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', 'https://some-url/api/accounts').as('Accounts')
cy.wait('@Account')  //Wait
```